# Action bar back ground doesn't change when split

Tags: android, background

I follow this tutorial from google about styling background of action bar 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html
But when i implemented split action bar , the top action bar's background is changed but the bottom one did not.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37599516/Untitled.png

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Menu shows in the bottom is not action bar ,its option menu.You have to set style for option menu .May this will help you

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);

getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
AttributeSet attrs) {

if (name     .equalsIgnoreCase(“com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView”)) {
try {
LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();
final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs);

new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
public void run() {

// set the background drawable
view     .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_ac_menu_background);

// set the text color
((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
});
return view;
} catch (InflateException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}
}
return null;
}
});
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help . i tried but i did not work . the result is the same with my problem

Comment: The problem is it can not go through if condition so it never run code inside if block